# Regular Expression Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to create a rails route that is capable of accepting requests using a regular expression. Specifically, I need optional paths. As an example:

> "(/first)?(/second)?"

Would match:

> /first
>   /second
>   /first/second

But not:

> /second/first

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this - regex looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to Rails 3 (now correctly supports REGEX routes).